# PHP. CURL. Номер ошибки, если истекло время ожидания ответа

Tags: php, curl

Нужно поставить ограничение на ожидание ответа (делаю так):

```
curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
```

Если время ожидания истекло, какой будет результат $code_error:

```
$response = curl_exec(...);
$code_error = curl_error($this->ch)["code"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
...
if(($content = curl_exec($ch)) !== false) {
  // все OK
} else {
  // ошибка
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но больше интересен код ошибки. Думаю что "28", но не уверен.

Comment: @Sublimer, все верно, у timeout код ошибки 28